# How to create a frequency table in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, longitudinal

I have a repeated measures of BMI over 50K people who took BMI measurements on different timepoints. What I want to know is the number of people who took only 1 measurement as well as for only 2 measurements and onwards.  How get it in a table with cumulative frequency like PROC FREQ from SAS?

I don't know how to do to get those mutually exclusive numbers in a table format.

Comment: `table(YOUR_TABLE$COL_WITH_ID)`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example> with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry as I am a beginner user of R. So, I do not know how to create a sample dataset for the longitudinal data. It's like each individual has a unique ID and the dataset is in long format based on the number of body weights they had taken. Some have only one row whereas others have 5 observations whey they took 5 body weight measurements. Thank you.